# IEs z-index issue

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index

In IEs (8-10), the clickable box is not registering but this works in Chrome and FF.  My guess is something to do with IEs z index issue.  Can someone please help me point to where I can find a solution for this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IFxKH/

HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" >

  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 9999999999999;
}
.box:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Please assume that this is how it has to be exactly mark up.  Having an image as a background is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, mouse events won't fire unless you have something inside of the div. Try placing a transparent gif inside of the box either as an img, or as a background image and that should solve your problem.

Comment: That does it.  I ended up placing a transparent gif (like suggested) and styled it with a width/height in CSS.  Thank you so much!